# Working with options in SML, pattern matching

Tags: smlnj

I am trying to build a get element from list function in SML:

```
fun get_nth e =
    case e of
    [] => NONE
    | (x::xs, n) => if n = 1
                  then SOME x
                  else SOME get_nth(xs, n-1)
```

This produces the following error:

```
hw1pm.sml:72.24-72.45 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: ('Z -> 'Y) option
  in expression:
    (SOME get_nth) (xs,n - 1)
hw1pm.sml:68.5-72.45 Error: types of rules do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  earlier rule(s): 'Z list -> 'Y option
  this rule: _ list * [- ty] -> _ option
  in rule:
    (:: (x,xs),n) =>
      if n = 1 then SOME x else (SOME get_nth) (xs,<exp> - <exp>)
```

I don't think I understand options well enough, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`get_nth` already produces an `option`, so there's no need to wrap it in another "option layer" with `SOME`.
Also, function application binds very tightly - as SML says, you actually have the equivalent of (`SOME get_nth) (xs, n-1)`, which means that `SOME get_nth` would be a function.
(If adding `SOME` had been correct, it would have been `SOME (get_nth(xs, n-1))`.)

The second error occurs because your pattern matching is also wrong; you can't have a list (`[]`) in one case, and a pair in another.

With those two fixes, you get

```
fun get_nth e =
    case e of
      ([], _) => NONE
    | (x::xs, n) => if n = 1
                  then SOME x
                  else get_nth(xs, n-1)
```

but it's more common to define a function with several pattern clauses than to use `case`:

```
fun get_nth ([], _) = NONE
  | get_nth (x::xs, n) = if n = 1
                         then SOME x
                         else get_nth(xs, n-1)
```